# Cannot copy Database.db to sdcard for showing data in my android app

Tags: android, sqlite

It's my first database app and I am testing the application on a real non rooted device. The application is working perfectly and saving the data. However when I try to copy the contents to the SD card for checking the result, an error shows up.

The command : cp MyDatabase.db /sdcard/MyDatabase.db

Error:  sh: cp: not found.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed BusyBox on that system?  If not, that's why.  It's saying that the cp command isn't found, not that the file isn't found.  After a quick search I found this, but I've never personally installed busybox on a non-rooted phone. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2195692.  At least if you have trouble, xda is usually a good place to get help.